# Newly opened pages load indefinitely, but load immediately when I hit refresh

Tags: windows-7, firefox, dns, internet

I've been having internet issues with my internet regularly since I got a new computer and new internet a couple months back. At first I was having trouble with certain websites occasionally failing to load at all. The page just sat loading indefinitely even though others were perfectly fine. After a period everything was fine again and all pages could load without issue but the problem kept coming back out of nowhere. These were big sites too, like twitter and facebook, so I'm assuming the issue is on my end.

Some research told me that DNS settings might improve it, so I tried using Google's provided ones from [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en) for IPv4 and IPv6

> The Google Public DNS IP addresses (IPv4) are as follows:
>
> ```
> 8.8.8.8
> 8.8.4.4
> ```
>
> The Google Public DNS IPv6 addresses are as follows:
>
> ```
> 2001:4860:4860::8888
> 2001:4860:4860::8844
> ```

And that seems to have improved on the random dropping of websites, but I've had a different problem appearing now on the same sites as before. Now they will sit loading indefinitely, but if I hit refresh at any point it instantly loads normally. Whether I instantly do it or wait minutes, a refresh instantly resolves the issue.

This does seem like DNS settings are what I should look at, but I don't understand how/what to change. If it matters, I live in Ireland. I couldn't quite tell whether this affected what settings I should use, and it *seemed* like Google's provided DNS IPs were being presented as universal ones but that might be a mistaken presumption.

Comment: If it is a DNS lookup issue then it should work fine after the lookups have resolved. That means 1) First hangs.  2) Somehow refresh fixes the hang in the browser, and **3) A third attampt should work immediately**. (Even if done from another browser).   Could you test that ?

Comment: Did you try: With extensions disabled? A new firefox profile? With a different browser?

Comment: @Hennes I tried that on one site, and it did instantly load in Chrome. Most sites seem to be working at the moment so I'm not sure if things are fixed or that just means a lot of sites have been 'cached' in some way.

Comment: Normally I would suggest `ipconfig /flushdns` to test further with, but I heard a few things about browsers using their own DNS rather than properly using the hosts...